# Skipped Iteration in For Loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

My for loop skips to the 2nd grade to be entered and I cannot figure out why this is happening. The output looks like this:

Type in Grade Number 1: Type in Grade Number 2:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Would you like to input grades?: ");
    String input = inputReader.next();

    if (input.equals("y")){
        String[] grades =new String[2];

        for (int counter = 0; counter < grades.length; counter++){
            System.out.print("Type in Grade Number " + (counter + 1) + ": ");
            grades[counter] = inputReader.nextLine();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: And the output you're expecting is ...

Comment: It looks like you never stop to listen for the number of grades, but at first glance that error doesn't match your symptoms exactly. Still, worth cleaning up and might fix your problem.

Comment: I've reduced your code down to just the key bits that cause the error. Hope thats ok, roll back the edit if not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next()` reads a word, not the whole line, and it doesn't throw away the line after that word so when you type the firstname, the Scanner is still waiting for a reason to consume the rest of the line.  Only when you call nextLine() for the first time it does that (I am assuming the rest of the line is blank)

Change your code to be

```
    String lastName = inputReader.nextLine(); // read the whole line, not just a word
    System.out.print("Student First Name: ");
    String firstName = inputReader.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

After

```
String firstName = inputReader.next();
```

You must call `nextLine()`. Indeed, `next()` doesn't consume the EOL, and thus when you call `nextLine()` in the first iteration of the loop, it immediately consumes the EOL after the first name.